# Is it okay to ask questions on architectures that lead to simple and manageably large list type answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Consider the questions like

> What are the widely used CNN architectures and the tasks they are used
> for?
>
> What are the widely used CNN architectures and the tasks they are used
> for?

allows to answer the name of the architecture, along with brief and optional details and the task they are used for.

Shall we allow such questions?

Answer (score 1):

We have had already [a similar question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15594/2444) in the past, and, in the end, I closed it as "too broad". It's unlikely that someone will have exactly that same question (i.e. it's unlikely that someone will be interested in a brief description of those *specific* models).

I don't like this type of question where there could be potentially many different and/or overlapping answers for multiple reasons.

1. A model that is widely used today may not be anymore in 5-10 years, so these answers would also become outdated.
2. A good answer to this question may require a lot of effort to write and prepare.
3. Nobody will probably be interested in all those *specific* models.
4. Answers could potentially overlap a lot, so we'd better just merge them in one single very long answer, which may also not be very pleasant to read

It would be better to ask for **examples** of models that could be used for the **specific** task that you want to solve. For example,

> What are *examples of* (or *the state-of-the-art*) models that potentially can successfully solve this specific task X or have been applied to solve similar problems to my problem X?

Of course, you should first describe your task X.

In fact, we created the tags [model-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-request) and [algorithm-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm-request) for this purpose.

Why do I like more this type of question? For multiple reasons.

1. If people are interested just in knowing 1-2 examples of models (in this case) that could solve their task (this can happen frequently in case people are new to ML), all answers should address their concerns.
2. The answers to the questions would require less effort to write, as people wouldn't need to make a review, but just need to come up with an example (and maybe also argue why they are suggesting it)

If you're interested in literature reviews, you could specifically ask for that. We have the tag [reference-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) that could be used in those cases.